# Get neighboring rows (2 above and 2 below) of a certain row in PHP while loop

Tags: php, while-loop

I have a table like so (after doing a query on it to order it by score):

```
+---+-------+------+
|id | level |score |
+---+-------+------+
| 4 |   1   |  30  |
| 3 |   1   |  35  |
| 1 |   1   |  40  |
| 5 |   1   |  45  |
| 7 |   1   |  50  |
| 8 |   1   |  55  |
+---+-------+------+
```

I will output that to php in a while loop. So each row in the while loop will be the same as in the table above.

Essentially what I want to do is show 5 of these rows in a table (in html), with a certain row (e.g. where id=5) in the middle and have the two rows above and below it (in the correct order). This will be like a score board but only showing the user's score with the two above and two below.

E.g. say the user is id=5, I want to show

```
+---+-------+------+
|id | level |score |
+---+-------+------+
| 3 |   1   |  35  |
| 1 |   1   |  40  |
| 5 |   1   |  45  |
| 7 |   1   |  50  |
| 8 |   1   |  55  |
```

I am wondering does anyone know a way of doing this in php?

Basically

```
//select query output is in while loop
//get a certain row of the loop
//get the two rows above it and two rows below it
```

Comment: I dont know the limitations on using PHP here but if you are able to run SQL, the LAG and LEAD window functions were created for exactly this type of requirement.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, this could be helpful for me in this exact scenario where I am getting the data from the database.. But my reason for maybe using php to do this is that I also will need to do the same thing but with data that is not being selected from the database (I am doing the same thing for 'total points' which is worked out in the php) - so it would be useful to do both of them in the same manner

Comment: How to run SQL from PHP - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44772139/how-do-i-run-an-sql-query-in-php

Comment: Yeah I know how to run SQL from PHP thanks. I am getting the data using SQL but am looking for a way of presenting it in this way using PHP (I know it can be done using SQL in this example but for another one of my scenario's I need to use PHP

Comment: `I am doing the same thing for 'total points' which is worked out in the php` - you could do this as part of the `select` statement in SQL to prevent needing to do it in PHP :)

Comment: @alexherm Could you show me an example of how I'd use the LAG and LEAD functions to do this please if you don't mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One method uses a lot of variables:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             lag(id, 1) over (order by score) as prev_id,             
             lag(id, 2) over (order by score) as prev_id2,             
             lead(id, 1) over (order by score) as next_id,             
             lead(id, 2) over (order by score) as next_id2
      from t
     ) t
where 5 in (prev_id, prev_id2, next_id, next_id2, id)
order by score;
```

An alternative method is something like this:

```
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.score <= (select t2.score from t t2 where t2.id = 5)
 order by score desc
 limit 3
) union all
(select t.*
 from t
 where t.score > (select t2.score from t t2 where t2.id = 5)
 order by score
 limit 2
)
order by score;
```

This exactly syntax may not work in all databases, but the idea can easily be translated in whatever dialect of SQL.  This also assumes that the scores are unique.

Comment: Hi, i've tried your second option but it is not giving me the middle row in the middle (it is at the top).. it is printing out the correct 5 rows but in the wrong order. Do you know how I can put them in the correct order?

Comment: @bb25 . . . The result set should be ordered by score.

Comment: @bb25 . . . As I point out in the answer, this may not work in all databases.  You haven't specified the database, but I'm sure yours supports something similar.

Comment: Thank you! Assuming the scores are not unique but I have another column 'timestamp'.. do you know how I would ammend the SQL to take in timestamp as well? So e.g. if scores are equal then show whoever got the score first above, or after below?

Comment: @bb25 . . . In the question asked here, there is no `timestamp` column and the scores are unique.  I would suggest that you ask another question, rather than continuing to "refine" this one.

Comment: yeah sorry I was trying to simplify it but realise I probably shouldn't have. I will edit this question because people will probably try to tell me it;s a duplicate question if I write another one lol. Thanks

Comment: @bb25 . . . This question has been answered.  Ask a new question.

Comment: I have asked a new question. Thank you